# (variable) annotation in python after method call

Tags: python, keras

While looking through Keras framework I have noticed an interesting style used there.

```
my_method(some_parameter)(variable_to_call_method_on_apperently)
```

Could you please provide any insights, what exactly is going on there, and where I can find more information about this?

p.s. I tried to google, but it is not use, since I do not know what to write in search bar.

**EDITED:** I am confused by the syntax. So, it is not Keras specific. I mentioned Keras trying to make my question more clear.

Comment: Is your question specific to the Keras framework, or are you just confused by the used syntax?

Comment: Obviously, `my_method()` returns a callable object, e.g. a function, which is immediately called. As for why it is needed in the particular case may require a code example from Keras.

Comment: I am confused by the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not keras specific. The first call to `f(x)` returns a value that is *callable* (that is a function, or an object with a `__call__` method) instead of a plain value. Then you go on calling the returned object with the second parentheses arguments.

You might also lookup *currying* and *partial application* for related concepts.